# What does "injection current" mean in the context of a microcontroller datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, current, datasheet

What does "injection current" mean in the context of a microcontroller datasheet? Specifically, I have the following on a dsPIC:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally the only current that'll enter the pin is tiny amounts of leakage sub micro amps but, if you have a signal input that is a bit higher than Vcc or a bit lower than 0v, substrate parasitic components may take more current and it is this current that must be limited to prevent device failure or improper working.

See the notes at the bottom of the table for how much more than Vcc you can raise an input and ditto for signals that might fall below 0v. This is usually only an issue when connecting chips of differing supply voltages. Basically, if you had a 10v logic voltage you could feed it into a 5v logic input if you used a series resistor of 1k ohm or greater. This would inject 5mA or less. Take note that you can only do this to a few pins before the total limit of 20mA is reached.

Answer (score 6):

Injection current is the current that is being forced into a pin by an input voltage higher than the positive supply or lower than ground. The current flows through the input protection diodes into whichever supply is being exceeded. Ideally, all inputs would be limited to the supply voltages, but the chip can tolerate small excursions above and below as long as the current isn't high enough to damage or disrupt the rest of the circuit.