# TIVA Injection Current

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, injection-current

I want to understand how the GPIO pins of my [TIVA uC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c129encpdt.pdf) will behave when the voltage is above Vcc or below GND. I assumed I could just Ctrl+F "injection current" in the datasheet and that would give me "input high injection current" and "input low injection current", like on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87483/what-does-injection-current-mean-in-the-context-of-a-microcontroller-datasheet). Unfortunately, that's not the case:

[image]
[image]

So, apparently, the datasheet specifies different values for the GPIOs and the pins themselves, but I don't understand how they interact. It *seems* to me that 
 \$ I_{INJ+} \$  and \$I_{INJ-}\$ are the data I'm looking for: if the pin is above Vcc+0.3V, it can sink up to 2mA (through the protection diode), and if it is below GND-0.3V, it can source up to 0.5mA (through the ESD clamp circuit).

If that's the case, then... what do the GPIO's \$ I_{INJ-}\$ and \$ I_{MAXINJ-} \$ mean? Shouldn't they have the same signal? Should I consider the GPIO injection current values or the pin injection current values when dimensioning protection resistors?